# When should you initialize a new variable and when you should not?

Tags: performance, go

I'm looking at the code examples [sql.query](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.QueryRow) and i'm a bit confused by the way the variables are initialized. As far as I understand the var keyword initialize the variable but if you already have a such variable it's better to 'reuse' it instead to reinitialize it. I'm aware that I might have misunderstood the golang specs so I hope this question would help me (and perhaps other folks) get it right.

```
  rows, err := db.Query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE age=?", age)
    if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    for rows.Next() {
            var name string
            if err := rows.Scan(&name); err != nil {
                    log.Fatal(err)
            }
            fmt.Printf("%s is %d\n", name, age)
    }
    if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

Why is the "name" variable initialized within the loop and not outside the loop ? (see below). Isn't it less performant to reinitialize it on each loop ?

```
//how I would do this
  rows, err := db.Query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE age=?", age)
    if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    var name string //outside the loop
    for rows.Next() {

            if err := rows.Scan(&name); err != nil {
                    log.Fatal(err)
            }
            fmt.Printf("%s is %d\n", name, age)
    }
    if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

or even better use a pointer

```
      rows, err := db.Query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE age=?", age)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
        defer rows.Close()
        name := new(string) //pointer outside the loop
        for rows.Next() {

                if err := rows.Scan(name); err != nil {
                        log.Fatal(err)
                }
                fmt.Printf("%s is %d\n", name, age)
        }
        if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
```

Comment: `name` is declared before the loop as otherwise it will be scoped to the if block and not be in scope outside of that block (read: you cannot use it afterwards). The loop does not reinitialise it; it just re-uses it. The block (loop) is after the variable declaration.

Comment: just want to mention that ``name`` is actually declared within the loop not before (in the sql documentation). It seems  to me that I missed the block scope thing. I didn't know the ``if`` (perhaps also ``for``)  blocks have that kind of isolation property

Comment: @hey: It's covered in the [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec): [Blocks](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Blocks).

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have determined that the allocation is a performance bottleneck, I wouldn't consider such a premature optimisation.  After all, it might not even make a difference, so it is best to err on the side of readability/maintainability.

In general, I'd suggest using the smallest scope for your variables that makes sense.  If they are stack allocated, then they will be quite cheap -- assuming space is available, it probably just involves initialising the variable to zero or its initial value.  Stack allocated variables scoped within a loop will probably end up with the same memory location each time through the loop too, so there isn't much to be gained from moving them out.

With that said, it isn't always obvious when a variable will be allocated on the stack.  If the compiler decides that the pointer passed to `row.Scan` could possibly be retained past the function call (that is, it *escapes*), then `name` will be allocated on the heap even though it has been defined with `var`.

Similarly if the escape analysis determines that the variable doesn't escape, the version that creates the string variable with `new` may decide to place it on the stack.

Comment: That's a bit annoying. For example I have some prepared statements so definitely the performance would be improved if they are not used correctly (i.e. cached ). However if a new connection / statement is initialized on each loop that makes them useless. I would like to declare them inside the loop but sometimes I get a "too many connections" error so I can only assume the Go initialize them on each loop thus the confusion about the go SQL example.

Comment: If you want to use the same value between iterations of the loop, it makes sense to declare the variable outside of the loop.  In your question though, you had a variable only used within the loop.